# Awesome font icons not showed

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, font-awesome, magento2

i have a problem in my website, biaterg.com; awesome font icons display as an empty Square instead correct icon. Can you help me? I have tried several thing; server locale is it_IT.utf-8, so i think it is correct; fonts folder exsists in the specific path. I'm losing my mind...
i have tried to switch to native language (en_US and en_GB); Problems remains. I tried on apache2 and on litespeed web server; server don't serve awesome font icon. If i try to change content in css from "\fd0a" to "\1f355", it works, but second code isn't awesome font icon, it's only css icons.
Please Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fonts awesome files are not linked. I added the link to GitHub and the icons appeared (see screenshot). Check the links.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN4rS.png)

Comment: Oh my god! You are great! Where do i put link?thanks thanks

Comment: Oh my god! You are great! Where do i have to put link?thanks thanks

Comment: Within the `<head>` tag with the `<link>` tag, like the other files you have linked there.

Comment: Raven I see that, if i write biaterg.com nothing is showed; but if i write biaterg.com/index.php, it works! How possible? Ca n you give me a solution? Please!!

Comment: The page loads just fine in my computer, maybe your connection is not working properly.